# System.OutOfMemoryException exception thrown SSRS 2012

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm developing a simple tabular report to fetch 20 columns with some WHERE condition.

My server details are as below: SQL server is 2008 with Memory 32GB out of which OS is using 4GB.

My development PC is having 8GB memory and I'm developing a report in SSRS 2012. I have written the query in the query designer itself to fetch the records. The number of records it has to fetch is around 500000. However, it I run the report from my development PC, error showing as "System.OutOfMemoryException exception".

However, with the same query, I'm able to fetch around 100000 records.

What I think is getting 500000 records is not a big deal for SSRS 2012. I'm unable to get why this error is coming up?

I think the rendering of the report is consuming my development PC's memory, not the server memory - Please correct me if I'm wrong?

I have 8GB memory and very less possible option to increase the memory of development PC. Apart from increasing memory, what are the other best possible options to try to overcome this error?

From my development PC , form where I can get RSReportServer.config ? Is there something I can do in this config file? Please suggest.

Note: Yes the dev PC is 64 bit OS. And, when extracting report to Excel is showing error: "An error occurred during local report processing. An unexpected error occurred in report processing. An exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown". However, exporting to CSV worked fine.

Comment: Do you need all the columns returned from your query? Is there grouping/aggregation done in SSRS that can be moved to the SQL Server box so you query returns less data? If you cannot reduce the amount of data coming back from the query then realistically you will need more memory, 8GB minus the OS , anti-virus and other basic servcies, minus the development tools will not leave much for your data.

Comment: I sometimes get this error, then I restart my PC and it works. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nn2FB1P_Mn8